# Getting number of rows affected from cursor in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, cursor

Below is my stored procedure which has 2 cursors inserting data into the same table. There is different logic in both cursors, which I have removed for this question. How to get the number of total rows affected or inserted during the whole operation?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Myproc] 
AS
    DECLARE @fetch_status AS INT

    DECLARE mycur CURSOR read_only FOR
        SELECT * FROM tableName

    OPEN mycur

    FETCH next FROM mycur INTO @Name, @Age
    SELECT @fetch_status = @@FETCH_STATUS

    WHILE @fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
        SET nocount ON;

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tableA] ([Name], [Age])
        VALUES (@Name, @Age)

        FETCH next FROM mycur INTO @Name, @Age
        SELECT @fetch_status = @@FETCH_STATUS
    END

    CLOSE mycur
    DEALLOCATE mycur


    DECLARE mycur CURSOR read_only FOR
        SELECT * FROM tablename

    OPEN mycur

    FETCH next FROM mycur INTO @Name, @Age
    SELECT @fetch_status = @@FETCH_STATUS

    RAISERROR ('Starting second', 10, 0) WITH nowait

    DECLARE @msg AS NVARCHAR(50)

    WHILE @fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
        SET nocount ON;

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tableA] ([Name], [Age])
        VALUES (@Name, @Age)

        FETCH next FROM mycur INTO @Name, @Age
        SELECT @fetch_status = @@FETCH_STATUS
     END

     CLOSE mycur
     DEALLOCATE mycur
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be **MUCH EASIER**, cleaner, and ultimately faster without using any cursors at all - like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Myproc] 
AS
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tableA] ([Name], [Age])
        SELECT Name, Age
        FROM tableName;

    DECLARE @RowsInsertedStmt1 INT;
    
    SELECT @RowsInsertedStmt1 = @@ROWCOUNT;
    
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tableA] ([Name], [Age])
        SELECT Name, Age
        FROM tableName;

    DECLARE @RowsInsertedStmt2 INT;
    
    SELECT @RowsInsertedStmt2 = @@ROWCOUNT;

    -- returned the combined count to the caller of the stored procedure
    SELECT TotalCount = @RowsInsertedStmt1 + @RowsInsertedStmt2;
```

Using the `@@ROWCOUNT`, you can find out how many rows were inserted.

Comment: so no need to have any cursor at all? what if i still want to use cursor then how we do that? i know about @@RowCount but when i write it inside cursor then it gives 1

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion: ***AVOID*** cursors whenever you can!!! Why would you want to use a cursor here - really ? ......

Comment: My actual cursor has some logic so i am not sure if i can avoid? nor i like the cursor because of looping

Comment: The "looping" of a cursor is **a horrible approach** when working with T-SQL - as I said before: ***AVOID*** cursors like the plague! 99% of the time, you can - and so you should do it!

Comment: should i edit question and add actual stored procedure so you understand?

Comment: Also from your approach how would SP return total rows inserted? because you use 2 different variables to hold the RowCount

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion: if you need to total - just add them up .....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245528/discussion-between-developmentismypassion-and-marc-s).